# Is there a way within a browser to determine if an attached media input device has been physically muted?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Many webcams and USB microphones have physical mute buttons and a common problem users have is figuring out why they can't speak (or use their camera).

As far as I can tell there's no way to tell the muted state of a device, and the browser does not receive events indicating changes in muted state.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that there's any events for physical mutes, especially if you can't find any documentation or anything.
One potential work around is check of there's any data coming through the mic or Webcam. If there's no data coming in then maybe alert the user, suggesting that a physical mute may be on.

Comment: Yeah this is pretty much what we thought. We do know that there is some mechanism for USB devices to communicate their muted state to the OS.

Comment: I'm sure this is possible, but it would change for each product. For the most compatibility, I would suggest writing some code to workout of there's any data. This will be able to work if it's muted, but also if it's disconnected or misconfigured

Comment: Given how common a problem being muted is in video/voice chat applications, you'd think that standardizing this stuff might be on someone's priority list (certainly OS / browser vendors). Oh well.